# call from java Main to methods in another java file

Tags: java, netbeans

When executing I have error: cannot find symbol in the line MyCalcs.MtgeCalc(); in file Main.java
Why is it so???
in file Main.java I have:-

```
 e/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.MyJava.002mavern;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       MyCalcs.MtgeCalc();
   }
}
```

and in file MyCalcs.java I have:-

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.MyJava.002mavern;
public class MyCalcs {
    public MyCalcs() {
    }
        public static double MtgeCalc(){
            System.out.println("mtgecalc");
            return 10;
        }
}
```

...just adding more text here to satisfy the post question data integrity checks but it seems a lot of text is needed here so i'll keep typing until I am able to post my question...

Comment: Java identifiers can't start with digits btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the packing name? As `user` mentioned, package name cannot start with a number. Try `com.MyJava`, instead of `com.MyJava.002mavern`, and the code will compile and run.

UPDATE #2: Besides the incorrect package, it seems not all the Java files are compiled. Try `javac *.java` to compile both Java files. Also, see these 2 Java 8 references for more information on the `javac` and `java` commands:

- javac: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html
- java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: My package name does not start with 002, I edited the package name before posting the question.  Apologies.

Comment: @DonaldWGarton Did you try to rebuild the project, after changing the package of both files? I assume the folders where they are in have also been updated. They will work. See: https://imgur.com/6YcXKeZ

Comment: @DonaldWGarton Are you building from command-line, or from an IDE like Eclipse? If you are building from command-line, can you share the command and the error that you are getting?

Comment: javac Main.java

Comment: @DonaldWGarton You need to compile all the java files. Can you try "javac *.java". If it works, I'll update my answer, and you can upvote and accept it.

Comment: thank you Geoff, no errors.  but where is the executable?

Comment: @DonaldWGarton The executable is the .class file which contains the public static void main method. Go to the folder which contains the com folder (If there's /myFiles/com/MyJava, you need to be in myFiles), and run "java com.MyJava.Main". See this guide for more info on using javac and java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html