# Declaring a Manager class that inherits from the Employee class (Java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a beginner in Java and I need help with how I can declare a Manager class that inherits from the Employee class and adds a bonus instance variable to store a salary bonus. I have this code that I can work around and a test program that I can supply to test it. Any suggestions on how to implement the constructors and methods here

```
public class Demo {

class Employee {

  int id;

  public Employee() {

  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

class Manager extends Employee {

  double bonus;

  public Manager() {
    super();
  }

  public double getBonus() {
    return bonus;
  }

  public void setBonus(double bonus) {
    this.bonus = bonus;
  }
}

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Manager m = new Manager();
        m.setId(1);
        m.setBonus(100);
        System.out.println("Manger has an ID of " + m.getId() + " with a bonus of " + m.getBonus());
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) You can't have fields and methods inside a method. Remove the `main` line. --- 2) Where is your `Employee` class. --- 3) Do you know what "inherits from" means? If yes, then why haven't you? If no, then (re)read your Java learning material.

Answer (score 1):

It will look like below. Study it, and see if you can understand it.

```
class Employee {

  int id;

  public Employee() {

  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

class Manager extends Employee {

  double bonus;

  public Manager() {
    super();
  }

  public double getBonus() {
    return bonus;
  }

  public void setBonus(double bonus) {
    this.bonus = bonus;
  }
}

public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager m = new Manager();
    m.setId(1);
    m.setBonus(100);
    System.out.println("Manger has an ID of " + m.getId() + " with a bonus of " + m.getBonus());
  }

}
```

Comment: I can understand the code better from what I've learned on Inheritance but I'm confused because I keep getting errors when compiling my code. Are you first creating the Employee class, then creating a separate class Manager, and another Tester class which holds the main method and the the println statement?

Comment: @carnage47 Actually I put all of them in 1 file, and named it Demo.java. You can create separate file for each, but they will need to be defined as `public` (i.e. public class Manager, public class Employee); In my example, I didn't put public. After that, you need to build/compile them together. Somebody asked a similar question yesterday on this. See my Answer and the comments in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375532/call-from-java-main-to-methods-in-another-java-file/61376371

Comment: @carnage47 If you've found my Answer helpful, please Upvote and Accept it. Have a good day! :)

Comment: Hey I'm just stuck on this part because it seems only the manager line is not letting me compile my code. I get this error in Netbeans "error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context Manager m = new Manager();" Do you know how I can fix this manager line?

Comment: @carnage47 I saw your edit. What you are doing is making Manager and Employee inner classes. They are instantiated in a different way; you can read more about this later. To quickly fix your issue, put Manager and Employee outside the demo class. See: https://imgur.com/sXfO4jS But ideally, these should be in different files.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with 3 fields id,name and Salary for Employee and manager gets an additional field bonus.The salary for Manager will have bonus component added to the salary.

For Employee class create an argument constructor and set all the fields.Create getters for the fields required.

```
public class Employee {

    protected int id;
    protected String Name;
    protected double Salary;

    public Employee(int id, String name, double salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }

}
```

The Manager class now will extend Employee class.Based on the requirement the only difference between employee and manager is the salary component.Since all the fields in Employee class is set as protected and we extend the Employee class the state of the field can be changed in the child class. 
In the Constructor of Manager class the salary will be calculated as salary + bonus.

```
public class Manager extends Employee {

    private double bonus;

    public Manager(int id, String name, long salary,double bonus) {
        super(id, name, salary);
        this.bonus  = bonus;
        this.Salary =  salary + this.bonus;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Manager mng = new Manager(1,"Manager",10000,100);
        Employee emp = new Employee(2,"Employer",10000);

        System.out.println("MANAGER SALARY " + mng.getSalary()+" "+mng.getId());
        System.out.println("EMPLOYER SALARY " + emp.getSalary()+" "+emp.getId());

    }


}
```

Comment: It should be under a package in a project.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to run the code as a JavaFX application.JavaFX is a Java library used to build Rich Internet Applications.Apparently your  query doesn't talk about complete requirement.How should your GUI look like? What are the input Fields? What are the operations (CRUD) to be performed and much more.The code for Employee and Manager class will serve as the backend engine and copying that to a JavaFX project will not work that way. Please provide details of what you are trying to achieve and what all framework/technology you intent to use.